# Fomantic-UI Searchable Dropdown Meta Search

Tags: html, jquery, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I'm using Fomantic-UI, and I have a simple searchable dropdown.

```
<div id="form_selection" class="ui fluid search selection three column dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="country">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Select Form</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <repeat group="{{ @forms }}" value="{{ @form }}">
            <div class="item" data-meta="{{ implode(', ', array_column(@form['categories'], 'category')) }}" data-value="{{ @form['uid'] }}">{{ @form['name'] }}</div>
        </repeat>
    </div>
</div>
```

This dropdown is initialized like this:

```
$('#form_selection').dropdown({
    ignoreDiacritics: true,
    sortSelect: true,
    fullTextSearch:'exact'
});
```

This loops through some rows in my database, which adds some options to my dropdown. For each of these values, there is 1 or more `Category`'s associated with it.
As you can see, I have an attribute called `data-meta`. I want the search within the dropdown to include the `data-meta` attribute in it's returns ([Similar to DataTables `data-search` option](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you find your solution? i have a similar problem, and yours seems the closest question to it.

Comment: @FF- Sorry, I think I had to roll my own solution to this, but can't remember now.